postgres, do you need both unique index and normal index?
our application has tables with what appear to be duplicate indexes, e.g.
CREATE INDEX mytable_myfield_idx on mytable(myfield)
CREATE UNIQUE mytable_myfield_key on mytable(myfield)

e.g.:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX campaigns_pkey ON public.campaigns USING btree (id);
CREATE INDEX idx_id_campaigns ON public.campaigns USING btree (id);

The question is, if you create a unique index, does this also do the job of a non unique index, i.e. allow fast queries like:
SELECT * from campaigns where id = xxx

I.e. is there an advantage to having both indexes on a table?

No, it only hurts because of the maintenance of both indexes and the extra space it takes to store both indexes. UNIQUE is implemented in PostgreSQL (and many other databases) as an index using a constraint. From the manual:

Adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique btree
index on the column or group of columns used in the constraint.

